# 子のfragmentのライフサイクルが期待しない動作をしている

Tags: android, android-fragments

`ViewPager`の持っている`Fragment`から子`Fragment`を乗せた場合に親の`onActivityCreated()`がローテートを切り替える都度複数回コールされてしまいます。

構成は以下のような感じです
Activity
　→ViewPager
　　→FragmentA
　　→FragmentB
　　　→FragmentC
　　　　    @Override

以下FragmentB抜粋

```
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    （省略）
    final FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    final FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    final Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentByTag("FRAGMENT_C");
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        ft.replace(R.id.c_fragment, CFragment.getInstance(), "FRAGMENT_C").commit();
    }
    return view;
}
```

以下のようなコードです。

どうしたら回避できるでしょうか？

FragmentCを追加する一連のコードを削除した場合FragmentBのライフサイクルは通常通り動いています。

Comment: `getChildFragmentManager()`を使っていないため、`Fragment`間に親子関係がないように見えます。